# Angular to Non-Angular pages breaks history, clicking back brings us to app base href

Tags: javascript, angular

We're migrating some of our website to an angular app. We're implementing the paths so that they match the old URL structure so we don't break links and don't have to redirect.

Using Angular 6

While navigating withing the angular app, the back and forward work as expected. It goes from route to route.

```
/angular/path/ -> /angular/second-path -> (back button) -> /angular/path/
```

When I navigate to a non-Angular page then click back, it goes to the base.

```
/angular/path/ -> /non-angular/second-path -> (back button) -> / (base)
```

When I navigate to a non-Angular page then open back button in a new tab, it goes to the correct page.

```
/angular/path/ -> /non-angular/second-path -> (back button to new tab) -> /angular/path/
```

It's using lazy-loaded feature modules, but to test I've tried using pre-loaded components. The same thing happens.

Am I missing something here? Is there a fix to make sure back works?

Questions from comments:

Q: Can you clarify by what you mean by "open back button in a new tab"? Also, what happens if you open /angular/path/ directly? – Vlad274

A: On Windows Crtl-Click, on Mac Cmd-Click navigates to the most recent address from the back and forward buttons respectively in a new tab.

Q: What happens when you enter the app from any one of the child routes directly i.e angular/path as in your example?

A: It renders correctly.

Edit:
I'm voting to closing this because it turned out to be an issue with the server. We aren't using the out-of-the-box file server and there's an issue with https.

Comment: What happens when you enter the app from any one of the child routes directly i.e angular/path as in your example?

Comment: Can you clarify by what you mean by "open back button in a new tab"? Also, what happens if you open `/angular/path/` directly?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. I added answers to your questions in the body. But it renders correctly when you type in a route and when I say "open back button in a new tab" I mean ctrl/cmd-click the back button which opens the last page in a new tab.

Comment: I'm closing this because it turned out to be an issue with the server. We aren't using the out-of-the-box file server and there's an issue with https.